# Prove the following set is compact

Tags: matrices, elementary-set-theory, compactness

$\def\R{\mathbb R}$Fix vectors $b\in\R^k_+$ and $D\in\R^k_{++}$, and a matrix $A\in\R^{N\times k}$. Here, $\R^k_+$ denotes the set of vectors in $\R^k$ whose entries are nonnegative, and $\R^k_{++}$ the set of such vectors whose entries are strictly positive.

I have a question regarding how to formally prove the following set $X$ is compact: 
$$ X = \{b + A^Tc \in \R^k_+ : c \in \R^N, D^TA^T c \leq 0 \}.$$

I can draw the graph in two dimensions and see that it is closed and bounded, but for arbitrary dimension, I don't know how to formally prove $X$ is compact.

Any help is extremely appreciated!!

Comment: Where are your quantifiers? Is $b$ a variable or a constant? Is $A$ a variable, or a constant? What about $D$? What is $R^k_{++}$?

Comment: $R^k_{++}$ means strictly positive (not including zeros). All the quantifiers are included in the set description

Comment: No quantifiers are included. The way it is written, your set makes no sense: Is $D$ arbitrary subject to the given restriction? Are you saying all $A$ such that there is some $D$? Some $A$ such that for all $D$? All $A$ such that for all $D$? Is $D$ fixed?

Comment: A is N by k matrix, c, b, D are column vectors as described in the set. Yes, D is arbitrary, but importantly it belongs to $R^k_{++}$ therefore, each entry of D is strictly positive. Maybe a better way to describe the set is$\def\R{\mathbb R}$
$$ X = \{b + A^Tc \in \R^k_+, c \in \R^N, A \in \R^{N \times k}, b \in \R^k_+, D \in \R^k_{++}: D^TA^T c \leq 0 \}$$

Comment: What I am trying to describe the set is $\def\R{\mathbb R}$
$$ X = \{b + A^Tc \in \R^k_+ : D^TA^T c \leq 0 \}$$ The quantifiers are as above

Comment: No, that is a worse way of writing your set. You still have not answered the question. Are you looking at vectors of the given form for *all* $b\in\mathbb R^k_+$, *all $c\in\mathbb R^N$, and *all* $A\in\mathbb R^{N\times k}$ such that *for all* $D$ etc, or such that *there is some* $D$ etc, or are you looking at all $D$, and if for some such $D$ there is an $A$, then you look at the corresponding vector?  Or is $X$ yet something different?

Comment: OK, so now it seems that $b$ is fixed in advance. Is this the case? Is $c$ fixed in advance? Is $D$ fixed in advance?

Comment: $$ X = \{b + A^Tc \in \R^k_+ : c \in \R^N, D^TA^T c \leq 0 \}$$. Thank you so much Andres for your time!! yes, it's my mistake not mentioning b,A,D fixed in advance. Maybe it's a better way now?

Comment: I've edited the question incorporating what came out of the comments. If I misinterpreted something, please let me know.

Comment: Yes! That what I meant..sorry for the confusing! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

First take the set {$x \in \mathbb R^k_+: D^T x \le 0$ }. Clearly this set only contains the zero vector since $D^T x = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1} ^k d_i x_i $ which is a linear combination of non negative values with positive coefficients. So letting $x = A^T c$ we get that the set {$A^T c \in \mathbb R^k_+: D^T A^T c \le 0$ } only contains the zero vector and hence is compact. Adding the fixed vector $b$ to this set gives that {$b+A^T c \in \mathbb R^k_+: D^T A^T c \le 0$ } $=$ {$b$} which is certainly compact.

Comment: Thank you Daron, but here, b + $A^{T}$c ∈ $R^k_+$ does not necessarily means $A^{T}$c ∈ $R^k_+$. Therefore, I think the set is not a singleton {b}

Comment: Well then the set can be either just b or the zero set.